# Java test management tools/frameworks?

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm looking for some kind of test (mostly jUnit, but not exclusivelly) management. What I have in mind is a tool that would allow to easily enable/disable individual tests based on configuration (xml file, property file or in DB etc.).

I was thinking that there must be some maven plugin that could do that, or some tool. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Sorry for the question: Why? Someone spend time to create the test, and then the tests will be disabled? I think it is better to spend the time in fixing the code/test, instead of spending time to find a tool that ignore the tests!

Answer (score 1):

There are Maven plugins for JUnit and TestNG that allow you to define which tests to run from the command line (or all).

Answer (score 0):

JUnit allows the creation of test suites.  With some care, you can tailor your test suites to match your "to be enabled / disabled" sets of tests.

Failing that, you could wrap the test suite idea with something that generates / references an XML file for configuration (if that's really the path you want to take).  Considering that it's all in a Java class, you might find it easier to do by another means (perhaps an properties file or just in-class handling).